# синхронизация VSCode Microsoft Edge

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

Вопрос следующего плана.
У меня на компе стоит windows 11 и ms edge. начал учиться на фронтэнд-разраба.
После установки VSCode, открыл проект и файл index.html в браузере и edge предложил мне синхронизироваться с редактором кода. Я, в качестве эксперимента, согласился и когда стал верстать, то заметил, что в devtools edge реализовано, что если меняешь стили и дописываешь теги, то изменения автоматически сохраняются в редакторе кода и наоборот, если в редакторе кода меняешь свойства, то изменения сразу появляются в девтулс.
Я узнал что есть расширение для VSCode, но оно открывает аналог браузера и девтулс внутри редактора кода, а мне очень понравилось, когда браузер с девтулс в отдельном окне.
Подскажите, как можно вернуть настройку когда отдельно редактор кода и отдельно браузер, но при этом изменения в девтулс сразу появятся в редакторе и наоборот?